Darkening in ReSTIR DI spatial reuse implementation
I'm currently implementing the spatial reuse pass of ReSTIR DI in my path tracer but I'm having some form of darkening/bias at the edges of objects (visible on the tall box + lightening visible on the left of the sphere, on top of the small box):

To try and debug the issue, here is what I did so far:

Only 1 light initial candidate.
No random in light sampling. The quad light on the ceiling is effectively a point light (hence the hard shadows)
Only one neighbor reuse
The neighbor reused is hardcoded to be 15 pixels on the right of the center pixel (hence why we only have the darkening on the right side of the tall box and not the top)
Using a visibility term everywhere to avoid bias.
Using 1/Z normalization factor (ReSTIR 2020 paper, Alg. 6), to avoid bias

All of this combined produces the image above.
Some investigations:


Top left: Value of the target function at the center pixel evaluated with the sample that "survived" the weighted resampling on all the neighbors.
Top right: UCW of the surviving sample
Bottow left: weight sum of all the neighbor samples resampled
Bottom right: the final $UCW$ that is then used to compute the final lighting contribution $f(r.y)*UCW$

Note that the grayscale intensities are tweaked so that we can see something (otherwise it would be too dark/too bright).
This show that either the target function value or the UCW of the neighbor is incorrect. I think the UCW is correct (?) since I use it in my RIS-only direct lighting implementation which converges to the same result as naive uniform sampling. The target function is then the only suspect left but it is pretty simple to implement and I couldn't find the issue after re-reading it several times.
I'm using weighted reservoir sampling for resampling the neighbors (and the center pixel). The weight I use for resampling is:
$\hat p_c(r.y) * r.UCW * r.M$
with $\hat p_c(r.y)$ being the target function of the center pixel evaluated with the neighbor's sample (left of the above screenshot) and $r$ the neighbor's reservoir. This should match line 4 of Alg. 6 of the paper.
void Reservoir::combine_with(Reservoir other_reservoir, float r_m, float target_function, Xorshift32Generator& random_number_generator)
{
    // ReSTIR 2019, Alg. 6, line 4
    // pHat_q(r.y) * r.W * r.M
    float reservoir_sample_weight = target_function * other_reservoir.UCW * r_m;

    M += other_reservoir.M;
    weight_sum += reservoir_sample_weight;

    if (random_number_generator() < reservoir_sample_weight / weight_sum)
    {
        sample = other_reservoir.sample;
        sample.target_function = target_function;
    }
}

My unbiased contribution weights $UCW$ are coming from the initial candidates pass and are computed after all initial candidates have been added to the reservoir:
void Reservoir::end()
{
    if (weight_sum == 0.0f)
        UCW = 0.0f;
    else
        UCW = 1.0f / sample.target_function * weight_sum;
}

The weight_sum of this end() function is computed when adding initial candidates to the initial reservoir:
void Reservoir::add_one_candidate(ReservoirSample new_sample, float weight, Xorshift32Generator& random_number_generator)
{
    M++;
    weight_sum += weight;

    if (random_number_generator() < weight / weight_sum)
        sample = new_sample;
}

My RIS implementation used for initial candidate sampling converges to the ground truth so I assume that these function are correct and so the $UCW$ used by the spatial resampling pass should be correct (?).
Any ideas on why my $UCW$ or target function is incorrect (if that's even the problem)?
The code of the spatial reuse pass is here if needed. Link to the ReSTIR 2020 paper.
